# How raise an grandchildren array, at the level of children

Tags: php, arrays

I have some problems with parent array that contains multiple children array. It will be necessary that the array children, does not contain themselves other children array, but if it is the case, then to raise these array grandchildren at the level of children.

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => ...
        [count] => ...
        [url] => ...
        [html] => ...
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => ...
        [count] => ...
        [url] => ...
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
            [name] => ...
            [count] => ...
            [url] => ...
            [html] => ...
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [name] => ...
            [count] => ...
            [url] => ...
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [name] => ...
        [count] => ...
        [url] => ...
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [name] => ...
        [count] => ...
        [url] => ...
    )
);
```

In the example `array["2"]` contain 2 array, I want that the 2 array go up one level and so become brothers and not children.

Can you help me please with the right function ?

```
function transformMultipleArraysTo1(array $multipleArrays = null)
{
    $newArray = array();
    if (!isArrayEmpty($multipleArrays)) {
        foreach ($multipleArrays as $array) {
            if (is_array($array)) {
                foreach ($array as $singleArray) {
                    if (is_array($singleArray)) {
                        $newArray[] = $singleArray;
                    } else {
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
                $newArray[] = $array;
            }
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Yona, can you please share the code you've tried to write already? That way we can help you fix it

Comment: Yona, please add it to the question

Comment: It’s not duplicate because i need to keep keys and values !

Comment: Is it even possible to receive an array with grandchildren being arrays? By that I mean, is it possible in your code, that you **may** get an array like you described? And if yes, is it avoidable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this solution, not the prettiest, but it works.

```
function RemoveThoseNastyGrandchildren(array $array = NULL){
  foreach ($array as $ckey => $child) {
    foreach($child as $gckey => $grandchild){
      if(is_array($grandchild)){
        $array[] = $grandchild;
        array_splice($array[$ckey],$gckey);
      }
    }
  }
  $length = count($array);
  for($i = 0; $i < $length ; $i++){
    if(!empty($array[$i][0]) && is_array($array[$i][0])){
      array_splice($array,$i,1);
      $i = -1;
      $length = count($array);
    }
  }
  //print("<pre>".print_r($array,true)."</pre>"); <---- To print it pretty uncomment
  return $array;
}
```

## The First Loop:

will iterate through all relatives, looking for the potential grandchildren. If it finds one of these nasty grandchildren it'll append it to their parents, becoming a <strike>grand</strike>**children** again.

---

After that we just have to disensamble the former grandchildrens bodies, and that's what ...

---

## The Second Loop does:

It's iterating through the changed array, looking for empty bodies.
Then return the freshly shaped <strike>array</strike> *familytree* and *whooosh*, you got rid of those GCs.

Comment: "if($array[$i][0] === NULL)"  is not the good one ! but 
" if(!empty($array[$i][0]) && is_array($array[$i][0]))" 
Anyway, thank you very much :)

Comment: @YonaSmilevitch I edited the answer accordingly. Please accept it, if the answer statifies you and solved your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I did